# Case of "letters" in this sentence

Tags: nouns, translation, case, latin

I was studying Latin, and I came upon this sentence:

> *Magister* (boys writing letters) *vidit*.

Translated, it means:

> The teacher saw the boys writing letters.

I was wondering, what grammatical case would "letters" be in that sentence?

Comment: Lower case, I guess?

Comment: ... As in grammatical case.

Comment: English nouns have only two cases: genitive and everything-else. English pronouns have an objective case, which would be employed here (*The teacher saw the boys writing **them***), since *they* is the object of the verb *writing*; but that&rsquo;s an English rule, which should not be consulted in writing Latin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Letters* is the direct object of *writing*.  If it were marked for case, it would probably be **accusative**.

But modern English has largely lost its case system; its nouns are generally not marked for case, so more properly I would say that *letters* **has no case**.  (Even in Old English, by the way, there was no accusative-nominative contrast for plural nouns like this one.)

English is quite different from Latin, and we cannot always use the same descriptions for both.  Instead of marking a direct object with a case system, in English we rely on **word order**.  As a result, we must say *writing letters* and not *letters writing*.